# How to change the color of b-table sort arrows in bootstrap 4 in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

[image]

I'm using nuxt and bootstrap but default sorting arrows in table is too dark for my background.
How can I change the color of the sorting arrows?

```
  <b-table
    show-empty
    small
    striped
    hover
    stacked="md"
    :items="rankingList"
    :fields="fields"
    :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
    :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
    :sort-direction="sortDirection"
  >
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.15.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^0.7.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vue2-transitions": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^0.5.1"
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `dark` prop to `<b-table>`?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this issue (which should not exist anyway because in dark table variant my arrows are white, so they are visible) is by overriding the css of bootstrap.

So for the table sorting arrows bootstrap uses the following 3 css

1. no sorting

   body .table.b-table>tfoot>tr>[aria-sort=none], body .table.b-table>thead>tr>th[aria-sort=none]{
   background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg
   xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='101' height='101' view-box='0 0 101 101' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3e%3cpath fill='red' opacity='.3' d='M51 1l25 23 24 22H1l25-22z'/%3e%3cpath fill='red' opacity='.3' d='M51 101l25-23 24-22H1l25 22z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")!important;
   }
2. sort (ascending)

   body .table.b-table>tfoot>tr>[aria-sort=ascending], body .table.b-table>thead>tr>th[aria-sort=ascending]{
   background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='101' height='101' view-box='0 0 101 101' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3e%3cpath fill='red' d='M51 1l25 23 24 22H1l25-22z'/%3e%3cpath fill='red' opacity='.3' d='M51 101l25-23 24-22H1l25 22z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")!important;
   }
3. sort (descending)

   body .table.b-table.table-dark>tfoot>tr>[aria-sort=descending], body .table.b-table.table-dark>thead>tr>[aria-sort=descending], body .table.b-table>.thead-dark>tr>[aria-sort=descending]{
   background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='101' height='101' view-box='0 0 101 101' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3e%3cpath fill='red' opacity='.3' d='M51 1l25 23 24 22H1l25-22z'/%3e%3cpath fill='red' d='M51 101l25-23 24-22H1l25 22z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")!important;
   }

if you notice inside each css there is a "background-image" property which points to an svg element.

Inside every svg element they are declared 2 "path" elements .

Each path element has a property "fill" .

You can change value of the property and point to any color you like.

In the above example i set it to fill="red"

Comment: You can check a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/bmzq3ecd/29/

Answer (score 0):

Here a css solution which works for me on Bootstrap 5+.

```
.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .both {
      background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}

.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .desc {
      background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAYAAAByUDbMAAAAZUlEQVQ4y2NgGAWjYBSggaqGu5FA/BOIv2PBIPFEUgxjB+IdQPwfC94HxLykus4GiD+hGfQOiB3J8SojEE9EM2wuSJzcsFMG4ttQgx4DsRalkZENxL+AuJQaMcsGxBOAmGvopk8AVz1sLZgg0bsAAAAASUVORK5CYII= ');
}

.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .asc {
      background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAATCAYAAAByUDbMAAAAZ0lEQVQ4y2NgGLKgquEuFxBPAGI2ahhWCsS/gDibUoO0gPgxEP8H4ttArEyuQYxAPBdqEAxPBImTY5gjEL9DM+wTENuQahAvEO9DMwiGdwAxOymGJQLxTyD+jgWDxCMZRsEoGAVoAADeemwtPcZI2wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
}
```

This changes the color of the arrow to green.